# How to concatenate follower characters to a string until a defined maximum length has been reached in Golang?

Tags: string, go, char, string-concatenation, maxlength

<kbd>**Input**</kbd><kbd>**Output**</kbd>
<kbd>abc</kbd>    <kbd>abc___</kbd>
<kbd>a</kbd>        <kbd>a___</kbd>    
<kbd>abcde</kbd><kbd>abcde_</kbd>

**Attempt**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "unicode/utf8"

func main() {
    input := "abc"

    if utf8.RuneCountInString(input) == 1 {
        fmt.Println(input + "_____")
    } else if utf8.RuneCountInString(input) == 2 {
        fmt.Println(input + "____")
    } else if utf8.RuneCountInString(input) == 3 {
        fmt.Println(input + "___")
    } else if utf8.RuneCountInString(input) == 4 {
        fmt.Println(input + "__")
    } else if utf8.RuneCountInString(input) == 5 {
        fmt.Println(input + "_")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(input)
    }
}
```

returns

```
abc___
```

**Discussion**

Although the code is creating the expected output, it looks very verbose and devious.

**Question**

Is there a concise way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [strings](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Repeat) package has a `Repeat` function, so something like

```
input += strings.Repeat("_", desiredLen - utf8.RuneCountInString(input))
```

would be simpler. You should probably check that `desiredLen` is smaller than inpult length first.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this efficiently without loops and "external" function calls, by slicing a prepared "max padding" (slice out the required padding and simply add it to the input):

```
const max = "______"

func pad(s string) string {
    if i := utf8.RuneCountInString(s); i < len(max) {
        s += max[i:]
    }
    return s
}
```

Using it:

```
fmt.Println(pad("abc"))
fmt.Println(pad("a"))
fmt.Println(pad("abcde"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ZWHEMxD3ll)):

```
abc___
a_____
abcde_
```

**Notes:**

`len(max)` is a constant (because `max` is a constant): [Spec: Length and capacity:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity)

> The expression `len(s)` is [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) if `s` is a string constant.

Slicing a `string` is [efficient](https://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_12.):

> An important consequence of this slice-like design for strings is that creating a substring is very efficient. All that needs to happen is the creation of a two-word string header. Since the string is read-only, the original string and the string resulting from the slice operation can share the same array safely.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do `input += "_"` in a cycle, but that would allocate unnecessary strings. Here is a version that doesn't allocate more than it needs:

```
const limit = 6

func f(s string) string {
    if len(s) >= limit {
        return s
    }
    b := make([]byte, limit)
    copy(b, s)
    for i := len(s); i < limit; i++ {
        b[i] = '_'
    }
    return string(b)
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/B_Wx1449QM.